# Forming a regular expression in Java to extract wiki links

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to  write a Regex in java to find and extract all the wiki links starting with /wiki that occurs after the first occurrence of a paragraph tag in the html source code of a web page. For example

```
<a href="/wiki/Computer_scientist" title="Computer scientist">computer scientist</a> 
<p>Its fields can be divided into a variety of theoretical and <a href="/wiki/Practical_disciplines"
```

This should extract /wiki/Practical_disciplines

I am not much familiar with regular expressions but after doing some research what I have came up with is:

```
ArrayList<String> wikiLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern wikiPattern = Pattern.compile("^<p>([a-zA-Z0-9+&@/%?<>\"=~_|!,.;])+^(/wiki/[a-zA-Z0-9+&@/%?=~_|!,.;]+");
    Matcher wikiMatcher = wikiPattern.matcher("srcString");
    while (wikiMatcher.find()) {
        wikiLinks.add(srcString.substring(wikiMatcher.start(0),
            wikiMatcher.end(0)));
```

I know this is poorly formed and far from being even okay. But if somebody could help me formulate a regex for this or guide me in the right direction, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: I'd recommend using something more like [jSoup](https://jsoup.org/) which has inbuilt searching capabilities

Comment: Regular expressions do only work for HTML parsing when you can be sure that the incoming HTML is exactly written to match your patterns. There are situations when you have that level of control ; but very often, using regular expressions is the wrong approach. So, depending on your context - consider if you aren't better off using a true HTML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this *regex* ...

```
<p>.*?href=\"(.*?)\"
```

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/5JmlvZ/1)**

**Java** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/dYPi1q) )

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class RegEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "<a href=\"/wiki/Computer_scientist\" title=\"Computer scientist\">computer scientist</a> <p>Its fields can be divided into a variety of theoretical and <a href=\"/wiki/Practical_disciplines\"";
        String r = "<p>.*?href=\"(.*?)\"";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much and thanks for providing a link for explanation as well, this really helped!